# How can I implement a vertical fullpage slider with Splide js without sliding multiple pages with mousewheel?

Tags: javascript, slider, vertical-scrolling, splidejs

I would like to implement a vertical full page slider with Splide js, just like this: https://codepen.io/sebastianomorando/pen/WPVWVr. But when I use a Splide slider with the mouse wheel options, it always slides minimum of three pages and not only one. These are the Splide options I set:

```
direction   : 'ttb',
height      : '100vh',
wheel       : true,
```

I also tried the other wheel options, like wheelMinThreshold or wheelSleep, but found no solution for this. Does anybody know, how to set the Splide options right, to get a smooth slider, which slides only one page per scroll interaction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you would have found an answer to your question by now but I'm still going to answer it. It might help someone else. You need to add perPage and perMove attributes. They both take a number value

Example:

perPage : 3
perMove : 1